# Mobx + React won't update rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm using mobx to open and close a popup modal(with react)

Unfortunately changes in the state are not reflected in the popup modal. What could be the problem?

Edit: I've added a sandbox with a simpler example: https://codesandbox.io/s/7z161kyv86

Comment: use `class AppStore` instead of `class AppStore extends React.Component`

Comment: @nrgwsth I actually had the code like that but it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decorate` doesn't work because of how Babel 7 transforms the class properties.

**Babel 7**

```
class Foo {
  value = 1;
}

// =>

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: 1
    });
  }
}
```

You need to configure the `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin to use the `loose` mode for it to transform it in the same way Babel 6 does.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties').default,
      {
        loose: true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Babel 6**

```
class Foo {
  value = 1;
}

// =>

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 1;
  }
}
```